# How to change value of this textarea?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, webbrowser-control

I want to set text on this [Website](https://notepad.pw/011hk762)

and its relative html

```html
<textarea ng-model="textarea" allow-tab="" open-url="" character-count="" bind-input="update_contents();" ng-change="update_contents();" class="textarea ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" spellcheck="false" placeholder="" style="font-size: 15px; height: 183.2px;"></textarea>
```

How can I change the value of this textarea if it doesn't appear on its html? I'm using a webbrowser control

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the HtmlElement by using:

1. [Document.GetElementByID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid)
2. [Document.GetElementByPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementfrompoint)
3. [Document.GetElementsByTagName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname)

There isn't any ID, so that rules out number 1. I'd personally use number 3 and use some debugging skills to figure out which item in the array is the TextArea that you need.

Once you have the HtmlElement, you would set its [InnerText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext) property to your desired value.

Here is an example demonstrating what you want:

```vb
Dim textareas = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
If (textareas.Length > 0) Then
    ' this assumes that the first item in the array is the desired TextArea, you may need to change the index
    textareas(0).InnerText = "hello world"
End If
```

Comment: Hi David,I tried your code with something like this :  Dim collection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

        For Each element As HtmlElement In collection
            If element.TagName = "textarea" Then
                Dim textareas = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
                textareas(1).InnerText = "hello world"
            End If
        Next

and even changing the index it doesn't work, it doesn't change the value.. Any idea?

Comment: Try setting up a breakpoint when you set InnerText and compare if the currently iterated textarea is the one you're expecting.

Comment: It doesn't seems to do anything. I think there might be some problem with the code. Open the website and have a look to the html code inspecting the textarea. You can't find the text "HELP" in any element, even if you select it and inspect.

Comment: @Mattia - I tried starting a fresh project, adding a WebBrowser, and setting the URL to the link you included in your original post. The webpage fails to load because the WebBrowser is build off of Internet Explorer (aka crap)

Comment: Hi David, you simply need to update your IE version creating a registry  key as here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189642/Browser-Update-for-WebBrowser-control-in-VB-NET to display correctly the website. Thanks